# How to replace line break and keeping the remaining string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a csv file, within the cells are comments which contains line breaks.

I have almost succeeded to select those comments

select: `("[^,])(.[^"]*)((\n){1,})(.[^"]*)(",)`
replace: I have tried `$1$2$3$6 and \1\2\3\6`

Example of string:

> Panthéon Sorbonne (Paris I),,,,,,,,,,,"More than 6 years in Finance
>
> Corporate Finance,  Mergers & Acquisitions,  Cross-border
>   transactions, Emerging Market in particular South America Mid Market,
>   all sectors Financial analysis,  Valuation DCF and Multiples Modeling,
>
> Speaking French, English, Spanish and Portuguese ",,,,,

Expected result:

> Panthéon Sorbonne (Paris I),,,,,,,,,,,"More than 6 years in Finance Corporate Finance,  Mergers & Acquisitions,  Cross-border transactions, Emerging Market in particular South America Mid Market, all sectors Financial analysis,  Valuation DCF and Multiples Modeling, Speaking French, English, Spanish and Portuguese",,,,,

none of these trials have successfull.

Comment: Try `("[^"\n\r]*)[\n\r]+([^"]*")` and replace with `$1 $2`, just click Replace All until no match is found.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this pattern brings ending quotes followed by a comma, that is why I have excluded comma in my pattern ("[^,])

Comment: @Toto I have edited the post

Comment: Your edit is not quite sufficient. I tried to follow your current pattern logic and `("(?!,)[^"\n\r]*)[\n\r]+([^"]*(?<!,)",)` -> `$1 $2` might work for you.